# Exchanging one bit with another in a integer, code does not work

Tags: c#, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

> Write a program that exchanges the values of the bits on positions 3, 4 and 5 with bits on positions 24, 25 and 26 of a given
>   32-bit unsigned integer.

So above is the exercise and below are my workings.

```
int number = 28;                                //number                         -0001 1100    28
int bit3 = (number >> 3) & 1;                   //obtain bit 3rd bit from left   -0000 0001     1
int bit3return = bit3 << 3;                     //return bit to possition        -0000 1000     8
int numberReturn = number & (~(bit3return));    //number with bit place reversed -0001 0100    20

int number2 = 20;                               //number                         -0001 0100    20
int bit3Return = 1 << 3;                        //return bit to possition        -0000 1000     8
int numberReturn2 = number2 + bit3Return;       //number with bit place reversed -0001 0100    28
```

Here is my final code.

```
Console.WriteLine("Enter a number to be modified:");
int num = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

int b3 = (num >> 3) & 1;
int b4 = (num >> 4) & 1;
int b5 = (num >> 5) & 1;
int b24 = (num >> 24) & 1;
int b25 = (num >> 25) & 1;
int b26 = (num >> 26) & 1;

num = num & (~(1 << b24)) | (b3 << 24);
num = num & (~(1 << b3)) | (b24 << 3);
num = num & (~(1 << b25)) | (b4 << 25);
num = num & (~(1 << b4)) | (b25 << 4);
num = num & (~(1 << b26)) | (b5 << 26);
num = num & (~(1 << b5)) | (b26 << 5);

Console.WriteLine(num);
```

Problem is, it does not work:

I input 56 which is:

- 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0011 1000

Output should be 117440512 which is:

- 0000 0111 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000

However I get 117440568 which is:

- 0000 0111 0000 0000 0000 0000 0011 1000

If I input 117440512  I get the same output, so 0 becomes 1 but 1 does not become 0. Please help.

Comment: You added the new values but didn't remove the old ones? (XOR/OR)

Comment: You might want to consider that you can extract all 3 low bits (or all 3 high bits) in a single operation. And that you don't necessarily have to shift them down into bit position 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example with input x

```
x = 1234567890              // == 0100 1001 1001 0110 0000 0010 1101 0010
```

Get upper and lower mask

```
umask = 7 << 24             // == 0000 0111 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
lmask = 7 << 3              // == 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0011 1000
```

Get the bits that we want to swap

```
y = x & umask               // == 0000 0001 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
z = x & lmask               // == 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0001 0000
```

Shift y to the lower position

```
y = y >> (24 - 3)           // == 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 1000
```

Shift z to the higher position

```
z = z << (24 - 3)           // == 0000 0010 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
```

Mask out old values

```
x = x & ~( umask | lmask )  // == 0100 1000 1001 0110 0000 0010 1100 0010
```

Put in new values

```
x = x | y | z               // == 0100 1010 1001 0110 0000 0010 1100 1010
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code is unnecessarily complicated. Think of manipulating with all three bits at the same time. The algorithm should be as follows:

1. Separate bits 3, 4, 5 by masking with `… 0011 1000`;
2. Shift left by 21 to positions 24, 25, 26;
3. Separate bits 24, 25, 26 by masking with `… 0111 0000 …`;
4. Shift right by 21 to positions 3, 4, 5;
5. Mask-out 3, 4, 5, 24, 25, 26 in the original variable by ANDing with '…1000 1111 … 1100 01111';
6. Mix-in the temporary results of (2) and (4) by ORing them to the results of (5).

Actual code implementation is left upon the reader.

Answer (score 1):

Given:

```
int b24 = (num >> 24) & 1;
```

Means that `b24` can only contain 0 or 1. Which means:

```
num & (~(1 << b24))
```

Will be clearing bit 0 or 1 of `num`. And then:

```
| (b3 << 24);
```

is either setting bit 24 (if `b3` is 1) or is leaving it at whatever value it currently has (if `b3` is 0). You probably wanted:

```
num & (~(1 << 24))
```

to clear bit 24 of the number.

(Apply same logic for all of the remaining lines. Each one repeatedly clears either bit 0 or 1 of `num` and then attempts to set a different bit's value)